# VS 2013 SqlServer Project: [dbo].[MYVIEW] has an unresolved reference to object [master].[dbo].[spt_values]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, database-project

I have already set the correct SQL Server version and added the master database as database reference.

There have been several unresolved references with the master database before and after adding the reference all of those disappeared.

Just this one did not resolve.

```
SELECT *
FROM   "master".."spt_values" C
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the unresolved reference?

Comment: I had the same issue with "sp_WhoIsActive", ended up just suppressing it using [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/22bc1ea0-d908-4b90-9d95-e2171635c8cc/references-to-syssysprocesses-generating-sql71502-warning-unresolved-refrerence?forum=ssdt). The only other resolutions involve some sort of [workaround](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6532bea-18aa-4708-a9cf-4e61f918c47b/sql03006-unresolved-reference-to-object-masterdbosptvalues?forum=vstsdb), I prefer to avoid that, it's too bad they don't include it in the default master DB reference, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

The *master.dbo.spt_values* view is an undocumented internal view and it seems the *master.dacpac* doesn't include it. This view is often used as a tally number table. If this is your case, you could use the Itzik's virtual table:

[Virtual Auxiliary Table Numbers](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers)

and you can replace the *spt_values* view with this function, that is better in performances.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please add a complete code sample to make this a possible accepted answer? Can you kindly add maybe two sentences what is exactly a "tally number table"?

Comment: I can't add a complete code sample if I don't know how the spt_values view is used in your solution. Please, add your code snippet where this view is used. Thank you.